# Displaying column value in primeng datatable

Tags: angular, datatable, primeng

I have the following primeng datatable configuration:

```
private cars : any = 
    {
        "data": [
            {    "time": "9:30AM-10:30AM", 
                 "Monday": {"Subject": "Physics"}, 
                 "Tuesday": 2012, 
                 "Wednesday": "Orange", 
                 "Thursday": "dsad231ff", 
                 "Friday": "dsad231ff"
            },

            {    "time": "10:30AM-11:00AM", 
                 "Monday": {"Subject": "Maths"}, 
                 "Tuesday": 213213, 
                 "Wednesday": "efrwr", 
                 "Thursday": "dsad231ff", 
                 "Friday": "aaaaa"
            },
        ]
    }   

cols: any = [
            {field: 'time', header: ''},
            {field: 'Monday', header: 'Monday'},
            {field: 'Tuesday', header: 'Tuesday'},
            {field: 'Wednesday', header: 'Wednesday'},
            {field: 'Thursday', header: 'Thursday'},
            {field: 'Friday', header: 'Friday'}
        ];
```

and html:

```
<p-dataTable [value]="cars">
    <p-column *ngFor="let col of cols" [field]="col.field" [header]="col.header"></p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

As u can see in data one of the value is an object `"Monday": {"Subject": "Physics"},` In the table cell how can I display the value of the object with key `Subject`? Currently i see an Object in my cell. Thanks in advance guys

Comment: Have you tried to use a template for the cell values?

Comment: I tried but end up failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@blackdaemon,

Update your cols configuration as below:
{field: **'Monday.Subject'**, header: 'Monday'}

PrimeNg refers to fields as objects.

Please try and update.